# Seeing all nginx variables

Tags: nginx

The nginx [HttpEchoModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpEchoModule) gives me access to individual nginx variables:

```
location /whathost {
    echo "This host is $http_host";
}
```

I want to see every variable that is available and their values, similar to the output of `set` (w/o args) in bash.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Below is the code snippet I used to display the list of variables found in the [nginx documentation here](http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html). I had to delete some of the variables as they were not available in my setup because they come from different modules which I did not have enabled by default. I used the default nginx image from official [docker hub page](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).

```
location /variables {       
        set $variables '<br/><br/> remote_addr: $remote_addr';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> ancient_browser: $ancient_browser';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> arg_: $arg_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> args: $args';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> body_bytes_sent: $body_bytes_sent';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> connection_time: $connection_time';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> connections_active: $connections_active';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> connections_reading: $connections_reading';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> connections_waiting: $connections_waiting';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> connections_writing: $connections_writing';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> content_length: $content_length';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> content_type: $content_type';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> cookie_: $cookie_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> date_gmt: $date_gmt';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> date_local: $date_local';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> document_root: $document_root';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> document_uri: $document_uri';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> fastcgi_path_info: $fastcgi_path_info';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> fastcgi_script_name: $fastcgi_script_name';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> gzip_ratio: $gzip_ratio';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> host: $host';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> http2: $http2';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> http_: $http_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> https: $https';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> invalid_referer: $invalid_referer';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> is_args: $is_args';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> limit_rate: $limit_rate';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> limit_req_status: $limit_req_status';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> modern_browser: $modern_browser';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> msie: $msie';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> proxy_add_x_forwarded_for: $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> proxy_host: $proxy_host';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> proxy_port: $proxy_port';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> query_string: $query_string';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> realpath_root: $realpath_root';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> remote_user: $remote_user';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request: $request';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request_body: $request_body';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request_body_file: $request_body_file';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request_completion: $request_completion';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request_filename: $request_filename';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request_id: $request_id';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request_method: $request_method';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> request_uri: $request_uri';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> scheme: $scheme';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> secure_link: $secure_link';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> secure_link_expires: $secure_link_expires';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> sent_http_: $sent_http_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> sent_trailer_: $sent_trailer_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> server_name: $server_name';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> server_protocol: $server_protocol';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> slice_range: $slice_range';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> ssl_client_escaped_cert: $ssl_client_escaped_cert';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> ssl_client_i_dn_legacy: $ssl_client_i_dn_legacy';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> ssl_client_s_dn_legacy: $ssl_client_s_dn_legacy';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> ssl_early_data: $ssl_early_data';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> tcpinfo_rtt: $tcpinfo_rtt';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> tcpinfo_rttvar: $tcpinfo_rttvar';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> tcpinfo_snd_cwnd: $tcpinfo_snd_cwnd';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> tcpinfo_rcv_space: $tcpinfo_rcv_space';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> uid_got: $uid_got';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> uid_reset: $uid_reset';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> uid_set: $uid_set';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_cache_status: $upstream_cache_status';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_cookie_: $upstream_cookie_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_header_time: $upstream_header_time';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_http_: $upstream_http_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_response_length: $upstream_response_length';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_response_time: $upstream_response_time';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_status: $upstream_status';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> upstream_trailer_: $upstream_trailer_';
        set $variables '$variables <br/> uri: $uri';            

        return 200 'Variables: $variables';
        add_header Content-Type text/html;
    }
```

It is definitely not a full list of variables as different modules and different version of nginx may provide different variables. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any programmatic way which we can use to iterate thought the list of all possible variables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a builtin way to display all the variables. But if you look at the source, they seem to be defined in:
src/http/ngx_http_variables.c

Look for `ngx_string`. Here's some awk to print them:
`awk -F\" '/[^\w]ngx_string[^\w]/ {printf "%s:\t$%s\n",  $2, $2}' src/http/ngx_http_variables.c`

Then you can write your own set function:

```
location = /set {
    default_type text/plain;
    return 200 "
# insert awk output here <-
";
}
```

You can find the source here:
http://hg.nginx.org/nginx

Or you can see the variables I found here:
http://pastie.org/9992530

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this isn't going to find a lot of variables.  Missing are anything that a non-core module brings in (like $proxy_host, $proxy_port) as well as variables that are set at runtime (like $invalid_referer).